# In org-mode, how to export sparse tree in buffer without unmatched top-level headings

Tags: org-mode

I'm using sparse trees to find tasks I need to work on in my buffer. The matching headlines are shown, without siblings but with their parents. For example, imagine I have the following tree:

```
* A
** A1
* B
** B1
```

And I use sparse trees to match and highlight B1, so emacs shows me the tree:

```
* A
* B
** B1
```

I find it very useful to print the whole buffer (export to PDF). However, when I set `Visibile only` to `True` and `Export scope` to `buffer`, top-level headlines that were not matched are also printed (in this case, `A`).

I tried to create a top-level headline that includes everything:

```
* Top
** A
*** A1
** B
*** B1
```

That way, the sparse tree is:

```
* Top
** B
*** B1
```

And, therefore, unmatched (now) second-level headlines, like `A`, won't be printed.

However, at this point, a second issue emerges: Most of my tasks are 7-levels deep in the tree. This is far too deep for emacs by default, so anything below level 5 is printed at the same level (meaning that tasks and subtasks are printed as if they were siblings).

If I use export options to include deeper headlines (`H: 10`), then they are printed as paragraphs instead of lists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You address two questions in this article. 1st: How to avoid the export of non-matching headlines of an org buffer with sparse tree. 2nd: How to properly print a tree with more than 5 levels. AFAIK on this site one question per article is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Once in the sparse tree you can either:

`org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` bound to the key sequence `C-c C-x b`

then you get separately a narrowed buffer with the tree down from where you point, expanding all headings, while keeping the highlighting.

**or:** `org-narrow-to-subtree` bound to the key sequence `C-x n s`

which will narrow while keeping the highlights without expanding any of the folded headings.

Whatever you edit in this buffer will of course affect the original document.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't see how this really answers my question. I'm trying to export to PDF... Please, see the details of the question, and let me know if anything is confusing.

Comment: @IvanPerez I am trying to be more specific. This answer has two issues: 1st: This command can only narrow/clone a single top-level headline. But it may be that there are more matching top-level headlines. 2nd: You manually have to go to the matching top-level headline at first. For an instance with the command `next-match`.

Comment: Tobias's export filter specifically answers your question. my solution was meant as a work around to get the levels that you wish to export into a separate buffer, in order to export.

Answer (score 0):

I only address your 1st question which is in my own words:

> How to avoid the export of non-matching headlines of an org buffer with sparse tree.

The following Elisp code defines an export filter that has only an effect if there are `org-occur` overlays in the exported org buffer. Those are the overlays highlighting headings in org sparse trees.

If there are any `org-occur` overlays in the exported buffer only matching headlines are let through by the filter.

When you have installed the Elisp code you do not need to set the `Visible Only` option anymore to export the sparse tree only. Just having a sparse tree view with at least one `org-occur` overlay is sufficient.

```el
(require 'org)

(defun my-org-export-only-occur (tree _back-end info)
  "Export TREE only headings with org-occur overlays if there are any.
Don't filter out anything if there are no org-occur overlays.
This is a function for `org-export-filter-parse-tree-functions'.
INFO is the plist of export infos.
We are using :input-buffer of INFO."
  (let ((input-buffer (plist-get info :input-buffer)))
    (if (and input-buffer
         (with-current-buffer input-buffer
           org-occur-highlights))
    (org-element-map
        tree 'headline
      (lambda (el)
        (and (org-element-map
             el 'headline
           (lambda (hl)
             (cl-member-if
              (lambda (ol)
            (eq (overlay-get ol 'org-type) 'org-occur))
              (with-current-buffer input-buffer
            (overlays-at (org-element-property :begin hl)))))
           nil t)
         el))
      nil nil 'headline)
      tree)))

(cl-pushnew #'my-org-export-only-occur org-export-filter-parse-tree-functions)
```