# Filter for tags in plain org

Tags: org-tags

I am sure this is a trivial question, but I just started out and honestly can't solve it.

I have a plain org file. Where I created a couple of headlines, which I tagged. How do I list all headlines with a given tag? `(org-tags-view)` seems to be the right tool for that. But calling it with `C-c a m` does not work, because after the `a` it tells me that `a` is undefined.

Edit:
Lets say I have a simple file: test.org

- header1          :tag1
- header2          :tag2
- header3          :tag1

Now I want to retrieve header1 and header3 and maybe its content. And I thought I can do that by typing `C-c a m` and "tag1". But C-c a gives me "`a` is undefined"

Comment: Could you provide an explicit step-by-step recipe to describe the problem you see?

Comment: With the filter at [the question about exporting only matching headlines with org-sparse-tree](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48549/2370) you can create a sparse tree with only the marked headlines and export it to a new org buffer with `org-org-export-to-org`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-c a` is the agenda shortcut, try running it directly using `org-agenda` in the run menu. You can also filter by tag inside the agenda buffer using the `/` key. Have you added this org file into the agenda files?

https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-files.html check this out, manually is basically `C-c [` in the org file buffer.

`C-c \` also works to search tags inside a org buffer, but I think the agenda buffer is way better dealing with multiple files, and it's definitely worth your time if you're using `Org-mode`.

Comment: Thanks, I stumble across it in my search, but excluded it because it did not seem to fit to my needs.

Has this an additional advantage, even if I don't want to organize dates and schedules?

Comment: I don't usually plan my stuff using deadlines since they are not needed in my life at this moment (I organize them by priority), so I end up using agenda as an uncluttered index of things that I have to do. It is an index of my org-files, I mark things as done inside the agenda view, because it's easier to deal with it, than navigating multiple org-files. You can also press tab in the agenda view to pop up a buffer with the org file and the cursor over the entry. I don't think there is anything better than that for this kind of purpose.

Comment: ah ok. I want to use it as a plain text substitute for citavi, endnote and so on. So when I read scientific papers (pdfs), I add notation via org-noter where each notation is a headline with a taq what this note is about. So this should more build up to a knowledge database, instead of an agenda file.

Comment: What's the problem with `org-match-sparse-tree` then? I don't think I get your problem, you got some org-noter annotations in a org file and your entries have tags. What exactly do you want to do with them? Export to an external file or just filter the file for visualization? I think it's the first one, since you don't seem satisfied with sparse tree, I think you could make a macro and refile the tagged entries check out how `org-refile` works. You can easily make a macro and run it through the entire file and put all entries in a second one. If it's not this, please explain it better.

Comment: Oh sry. org-match-sparse-tree works for me. I just added this comment to ask, whether the agenda mode could add anything to my workflow which I am just not aware about.

However, the org-refile option looks interesting, I will give it a try, maybe this is even better. Thanks